# Prove if $\left\{ x_{n}\right\} $ converge then $\left\{ \mid x_{n}\mid\right\} $ converge.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Good morning, i have an dude with this prove. Please help me

Problem:

Prove if $\left\{ x_{n}\right\}   $ converge then $\left\{ \mid x_{n}\mid\right\}   $ converge.

---

Proof:

Be $\left\{ x_{n}\right\}   $ convergent we're going to prove $\left\{ \mid x_{n}\mid\right\} $ converge.

---

Case 1: ($x_{n}>0$ converge.)

Be $x_{n}>0$ exist $N\epsilon\mathbb{N} $ if $n>N$ then $\mid x_{n}-x\mid<\epsilon$ $\Rightarrow$ $lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}x_{n}=x$ and converge.

---

Case 2: ($x_{n}<0$ converge.)

Be $x_{n}<0$ exist $N\epsilon\mathbb{N} $ if $n>N$ then $\mid-x_{n}-x\mid<\epsilon$ but...

$\mid x_{n}+x\mid=\mid-x_{n}-x\mid$ and $\mid x_{n}-x\mid<\mid x_{n}+x\mid$
$\Rightarrow\mid x_{n}-x\mid<\epsilon$ then $lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}x_{n}=x$ and that converge, and $\left\{ \mid x_{n}\mid\right\} $ converge.

I make the proof, but i don't know if is fine.

Comment: Use the reverse triangle inequality.

Comment: But my proof not work? @Cat

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint**

$$\big||a|-|b|\big|\leq |a-b|,$$
for all $a,b\in\mathbb R$.

**Added**

**First way**

Let $$\lim_{n\to \infty }x_n=x.$$
Let $\varepsilon>0$. By definition, there is $N\in\mathbb N$ s.t. $$|x_n-x|<\varepsilon$$
whenever $n\geq N$.

Since $$\big||x_n|-|x|\big|\leq |x_n-x|,$$
you have that $$\big||x_n|-|x|\big|<\varepsilon$$
whenever $n\geq N$, and this prove that $(|x_n|)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ converge (to $|x|$).

**Second way**

Since $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ converge, it's a Cauchy sequence. Let $\varepsilon>0$. Then, there is an $N\in\mathbb N$ s.t. $$|x_n-x_m|<\varepsilon$$
when $n,m\geq N$. Since $$\big||x_n|-|x_m|\big|\leq |x_n-x_m|,$$
you have that $$\big||x_n|-|x_m|\big|<\varepsilon$$
whenever $n\geq N$, and thus $(|x_n|)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is a Cauchy sequence, and thus it's convergent.

Comment: But i don't understand where i use that?, my proof don't work?

Comment: I completed my answer. (no your proof doesn't work).

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, your tentative of proof is incorrect. First of all, it doesn't treat all the cases. E.g. if $x_n=-1+1/n$ then $x_n\to -1$ but its terms are neither all positive nor all negative ($x_1= 0$ but $x_n<0$ for all $n\geq 2$). In fact, it can be worse than that: the sequence can have infinitely many negative terms and infinitely many positive ones: e.g.
$$
x_n=\begin{cases}
-\frac{1}{n},\quad\text{if $n$ is even}\\
 \frac{1}{n},\quad\text{if $n$ is odd};
\end{cases}
$$ note that $x_n\to 0$.

Moreover, your ''Case 2'' is incorrect for several reasons. There you should prove that $-x_n$ converges to $-x$, so that given $\varepsilon>0$ you want to find a sufficiently large $N\in\mathbb{N}$ so that $\lvert -x_n - (-x)\rvert=\lvert x-x_n\rvert$ (rather than $\lvert -x_n - x\rvert$) is less than $\varepsilon$ for all $n\geq N$. Also, you should not be able to say that $\lvert -x_n - x\rvert<\varepsilon$, etc.

The proof for your exercise is the following: let $x\in\mathbb{R}$ be the limit of $(x_n)$; then
$$
\lvert\lvert x_n\rvert-\lvert x\rvert\rvert\leq\lvert x_n-x\rvert\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0.
$$ Explicitly, since $x_n\to x$, given $\varepsilon>0$, let $n_0\in\mathbb{N}$ be such that
$$
n\geq n_0\Rightarrow\lvert x_n-x\rvert<\varepsilon. 
$$ Then, since
$$
\lvert\lvert a\rvert-\lvert b\rvert\rvert\leq\lvert a-b\rvert,\quad\forall a,b\in\mathbb{R},
$$ it follows that
$$
n\geq n_0\Rightarrow\lvert\lvert x_n\rvert-\lvert x\rvert\rvert\leq\lvert x_n-x\rvert<\varepsilon,
$$ as we wanted.

Comment: @Bvss12 you're welcome! thanks!